# pass int data via bundle

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a quiz `application` whereby i need to review answered questions after each quiz session. So, am passing the number of questions attempted as an int value with a bundle to the next activity.

So, am looping forward and backwards against my `array` of questions in which the index limit is the int which was passed from previous `activity`. However, am having some trouble as it isn't looping correctly. How do i get round this?

**Question Class**

```
class Question{
    // array of questions
    private String mQuestions [] = {
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
    // method returns number of questions
    int getLength(){
        return mQuestions.length;
    }

    // method returns question from array textQuestions[] based on array index
    String getQuestion(int a) {
        return mQuestions[a];
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("quizNumber", mquizNumber);
startActivity(intent);
```

**ResultsActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class);
                Bundle exBundle= getIntent().getExtras();
                int intValue= 0;
                if (exBundle != null) {
                    intValue = exBundle.getInt("quizNumber");
                }
               intent.putExtra("quizNumber", intValue);
                startActivity(intent);
```

**ReviewActivity.java**

```
public class ReviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Question mQuestionLibrary = new Question();
private TextView mQuestionText;
 private int intValue; // int value from quiz activity to be passed here
    private int mQuestionNumber = 1; // current question number
//navigation buttons for looping through array
    private Button mPrevious;
    private Button mNext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beginner_review);
        mQuestionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        //setting buttons
        mPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        mNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        // retrieve the number of attempted questions int value from quizActivity in Bundle
        Bundle exBundle= getIntent().getExtras();
       intValue = 0;
        if (exBundle != null) {
            intValue = exBundle.getInt("quizNumber");
        }
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateQuestion(true);
            }
        });
        mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateQuestion(false);
            }
        });
    }
// logic for looping through array.
    private void updateQuestion(boolean forward) {
        animateAnswerButton();
        if(forward && mQuestionNumber < intValue //using mQuestion.getLength() works for looping full length of array but i want to check against int data)
            mQuestionNumber++;
        else if (mQuestionNumber>0)
            mQuestionNumber--;
        mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you put data to intent?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("quizNumber", mquizNumber);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null){
                if(extras.containsKey("quizNumber")) {



                           intValue=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("quizNumber")

                    }
                }

    updateQuestion(true,intValue);

or

     updateQuestion(false,intValue);



 private void updateQuestion(boolean forward, int intValue) {
            animateAnswerButton();
// also print toast of int value for checking value
            if(forward && mQuestionNumber < intValue //using mQuestion.getLength() works for looping full length of array but i want to check against int data)
                mQuestionNumber++;
            else if (mQuestionNumber>0)
                mQuestionNumber--;
            mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        }
```

Also toast or log your `mquizNumber` in `MainActivity` whether you're putting correct value in bundle or not.

Comment: am getting the int value rightly. however, even with your code, it doesnt loop correctly. I want the loop to be restricted to the length of the int value passed.

Comment: what is mQuestionLibrary?

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**In your sender class**

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putInt("DATA", value);
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

**in your reciver class**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…

String venName = bundle.getInt("DATA");
```

Comment: I am actually getting the int data correctly. Where i have the problem is my logic to check against the int value when looping through my array

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this.

```
class DataStore{/*New class DataStore*/

public static int quizNumber=0;

}
```

/*Mainactivity*/

```
DataStore.quizNumber=mquizNumber;
startActivity(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
```

/*ReviewActivity*/

```
intValue=DataStore.quizNumber;
```

Comment: still having the same problem